# overflow-y: hidden on window height > x px not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I am doing it like this but it doesn't seems to work in ie7

```
if($(window).height() > 700){
            $('body').css({'overflow-y':'hidden'});

        }else{
             $('body').css({'overflow-y':'visible','height':'700px'});
            
        }
```

it does work in all other browsers

any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It is a well-known bug in IE6 and IE7. To solve it, you need to add position:relative to the container. Since in your case body is the container, I'd suggest you add a div directly under the body and give it position:relative. It should solve your problem."

See if this helps

[IE6 + IE7 CSS problem with overflow: hidden; - position: relative; combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo)

Comment: What about applying it to rhe HTML tag?

Comment: try. Give it an id="main" and then apply the overflow to #main.
I'm not too sure if ie7 will treat <html> just as a <div>