# Positioning absolute inside list with positioning relative for jQuery animation

Tags: css

Im trying to achive an animation of a horizontal list.

Like

- Item 1 * Item 2 * Item 3 * Item 4

But only two items is visible at one time.

Each item contains a div with a picture, a text and a link. The picture should always be aligned to top and the link to the bottom.

```
<ul>
<li><div>
<img src="somepic"/>
<p>SomeText</p>
<a href="url">Link</a>
</div></li>
<li><div>
<img src="somepic2"/>
<p>SomeText2</p>
<a href="url2">Link2</a>
</div></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the problem, the list-item must be positioned with "postition:relative" and if i use absolute positioning inside the div the animation gets messed up. I animate by appending and prepending to the list.

Does anyone have a nice and easy solution to this?

EDIT:

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/39bhW/

I think i need the positioning to be absolute within the list items...

Comment: Maybe you have a fiddle link or something that explains your problem more practical? The restrictions you describe are blurry, could you f.ex set the link absolute to the bottom of the DIV?

Comment: whenever you use absolute position keep in mind without css dimensions the element has 0 width and height

Comment: Please paste your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: johan, without seeing an example/demonstration (http://jsfiddle.net) of what you're after/where you're at, it's hard to know what you need help with.

Comment: @JaredFarrish You're right :) Added a sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you apply positioning to an element, it will use the positioning available on it's parents. If none is provided, it will position to the body element. So when you `position: absolute` to get the text/link at the bottom of the element, you have to `position: relative` (or `position: absolute`) one of it's parents, otherwise it won't know which you want it to position in relation to. Conversely, whichever it finds first, it will use that element to position against.

I think it's possible you've got too much markup to accomplish what you're doing here (what is the `.placeholder` for? why not just use the `li`?), and the `span`s that wrap one of the blocks looks out of place (and should be a `div` if you really need a wrapper there). And I'm not sure, but you might want to change `#items` to a class, if you need to reuse it. It looks out of place as an `id`. And your id and class names are not descriptive, and your selectors are not specific enough (generally, stay away from `ul` and `li` for styling specific parts of a page, as these have a global effect).

Nonetheless, I think this is what you're looking for. Note how I use `padding` on `#items li`, and then compensate `bottom: 5px`. You also don't need to position the `img` tag if it's just going to be at the top of the block, centered.

**HTML (Fragment)**

```
<li>
    <div class="itemplaceholder">
        <img src="http://www.els.qut.edu.au/blendedlearning/blackboard/graphics/test_on.gif"/>
        <p>
            Test title<br/>
            Description A
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#items {
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#items li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#items .itemplaceholder {
    height:200px;
    width:160px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.placeholder {
    width:640px;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    width:800px;
    height:240px;
}
#items .itemplaceholder p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
#items .itemplaceholder p a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39bhW/3/

Comment: Thanks alot! But this works incredibly bad in IE7 you don't happen to know how this could be solved?

Comment: It's a combination of two problems: Use `left: 0` on the `p` and `a`, and [see IE 6/7's mishandling of `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo). You can "fix" the second by giving a width/height and `overflow: hidden` to the `ul` as well. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/39bhW/6/).

Comment: "When you apply positioning to an element, it will use the positioning available on it's parents. If none is provided, it will position to the body element." - saved my life :D

Answer (score 0):

so basically you want to have 2 items visible at one time, am i right?

well, change the width of `.placeholder` to `320px`

Comment: Thats not the big deal. I want the link aligned to bottom and the text to be at the same level regardless of image size

Comment: At the same height in each item. Lets say 40px from the bottom of the div.