# Div Wrapping In IE6 Only

Tags: css, html, css-float, internet-explorer-6

You can see the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WuVz/7/

This works in all other browser (image top) but when viewed in ie6 (image bottom) it wraps incorrectly:

[image]

Note: You can see this in later versions of IE by using compatibility view and selecting IE5 Quirks.

Comment: seriously, the problem here is Quirks mode. If you're writing a site that requires quirks mode, even in IE6, then you're doing it wrong. You're deliberately introducing browser bugs... no wonder it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, the div that holds your title doesn't have a set width. Therefore, IE is telling it to expand, and as it expands, it shifts downward, where there's space. Try setting a width for IE6 only and see if that fixes it.

Additionally, [IE6 has some issues with `overflow: hidden`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo). Though it's usually in combination with `position: relative`, you may be running into something similar. If the previous solution doesn't work, you could try this.

**Edit** - Since you don't want to set an explicit width, I've thought of a few other options left to you:

1. Explicitly set `clear: none` on the non-floated element
2. Use a `span` element instead of `div` for the text in question (`span` is inline, while `div` is block, so it shouldn't expand to the parent width; given what you're doing, it probably makes more semantic sense to use `span`, anyway).
3. Use JavaScript to determine the width of the floated `div` for IE6, and set a size on the non-floated `div` accordingly (again, you can use conditional comments in your HTML to target IE6 exclusively)
4. Seriously consider whether it's worth supporting IE6 (ie - if this is on a site where the audience is fairly tech-savvy, you can probably forego IE6 support entirely, or at the very least, fixing this problem will cost your project more than the returns you get; but if you're dealing with healthcare providers, you probably have to still deal with IE6).

IE6 has a non-standard box model, which tells block-level elements to expand the full width of their container, instead of "shrink-wrapping" to their content. Their content is larger than the width they're allowing, and the `float` property takes the floated elements out of the document flow (which is why your `overflow: hidden`, when turned to `overflow: visible`, runs over top the floated content). The newer browsers have basically an "updated definition" (so to speak) of the `float` property, which tells sibling content to flow around the floated element, in addition to taking it out of the normal document flow. [CSS-tricks has a good article on float](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), as does [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/), if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply, Not having a width is the entire point, so that isn't an option.  I want the content on the right to push the title and resize it.  The content on the left has the potential to grow quite a lot, and its much more important than the title.  You can see my edits here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WuVz/20/

Comment: the left is the title isn't it? if you want the title to wrap at a certain point, then put a width. I don't understand why you can't have a width

Comment: I don't want it to wrap at a certain point if you look at the images above the top example with the ellipsis is the correct one the bottom one is the incorrect one.