# jcarousel not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, jcarousel

I am using `jcarousel` on [this](http://frontend.iwssites.com/creighton/home.html) page and it works fine in all browsers except *IE7*

The slides should only be 3 at a time in the middle of the arrows. Everything is functioning correctly except in *IE7* slides are overflowing outside of container. I was thinking it might be a *CSS* issue but haven't had any luck with *IE7* specific fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate this ( bug / MS feature)  in IE.

If you use `overflow:hidden` on an element that does not have both `width` and `height` declared it will not work in <= IE7.

If you can, try giving `#carousel_container` a height attribute. (by measuring the height of the element of the page in FF it needs to be 330px)

Comment: I created an ie7 css stylesheet that i am calling via condition comment. i added this code per your suggestion but it didnt seem to fix the issue. i still see all the slides:

#carousel_container {width:1140px; height:330px;margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;padding-top:10px;border:1px solid #000;}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo take a look at this. I think it'll help you.

Comment: No problems at all, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: putting a position:relative on the carousel_container worked in terms of bringing it down to only 3 images in the slider but now there is some spacing issue im having trouble with. if i change the width of the container than the arrows disappear.

Comment: Did you fix this? Another horrible anomaly for IE7 where you have the supposed: 'overflow:hidden' div hiding content but not width. Oh joy. I love IE7

Comment: i was able to fix it just enough to make it look okay in IE