# jcarousel not displayed correctly in IE before 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, jcarousel

I have got a problem with a slider at http://npl.ibles.pl

IE8 does not display it at all. In IE7 and IE6 images are misplaced. Have you got any suggestions what is wrong in the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works fine in IE8.

The problem with the `overflow` in IE7 is allready described here
[jcarousel not working in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612366/jcarousel-not-working-in-ie7)

I would suggest you to forget about IE6, this browser is over 10 years old and you can check its "importance" in the browser stats. It's just a waste of time.
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp