# Scope/Depth of CSS overflow property

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div style = "overflow: hidden; height: 5em" id = "selections-outer-wrapper">
    <div id = "selections-inner-wrapper" style = "position: relative">
        <ul style = "text-align:left; width: 12em;">
             <!---- LOTS OF LI ELEMENTS GO HERE ---->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My intention here is that anything within the outermost DIV should be hidden (clipped) if it extends beyond `5em` in height. (That is the purpose of the `overflow: hidden` style attribute.)  When I render this HTML using Firefox or any Webkit-based browser, the inner content is correctly clipped.

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Q82N9/

Screenshot with Firefox:

[image]

**However, with IE-7 it doesn't work correctly.**  (surprise, surprise)  For some reason, the inner `UL` element is not clipped, despite the `overflow: hidden` property.

Screenshot with IE-7:

[image]

It seems the problem is the `position: relative` styling attribute in the inner-DIV.  If I remove that style attribute, it works fine on IE-7.  However, I need the inner-DIV to have a `relative` position, because certain Javascript code that I'm working with assumes it does in order to scroll it up and down.

***Question:*** So, is there some reason this isn't working on IE-7?  Is this a well-known problem with a workaround?  Or is IE-7 actually doing the right thing and for some reason relatively positioned nodes can't be `hidden` using the `overflow` property.

Comment: have you tried setting `position` on the parent as well?

Comment: That's not a screenshot of IE7. (That said, this does actually happen on IE7.)

Comment: Wait... you're right, I'm sorry that's IE-6

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo) similar to the issue you've described?

Comment: it's a very old known bug in ie6 as well as ie7 - http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie, http://www.epigroove.com/blog/how-to-fix-ie-6-and-overflow-hidden

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo

Comment: POINT # 5 - http://stylisticweb.com/design-tutorials/15-ie6-bugs-and-simple-solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to container with the overflow declaration, and problem should be solved.