# IE11: overflow: hidden doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

It's not the IE6 bug of `position: relative` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo), and I couldn't figure out why. When the child div animates beyond its parent's border some part of it still flickers for a split second before disappearing properly.

Comment: If you're downvoting, give feedback, so I know how to improve next time, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was the attribute `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` series added to force render the div. I added all four of them using `LESS`'s method, but only the first one is really in use.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Remove the last one and it's fixed.